# How can i select a 2nd of the last row with inner join?

Tags: sql-server

All I'm a beginner in SQL server queries I practice queries and I have a difficulty in selecting the last 2nd row this is my queries code.

```html
select
 top 1 * 
from (select
   top 2 * 
  from MemberSample ms 
   inner join sample1 s1
  on s1.MemberId = ms.MemberId
   inner join sample2 s2
  on s2.MemberId = s1.MemberId
   inner join sample3 s3
  on s3.MemberId = s2.MemberId
  where ms.MemberId = '001' and s1.creationdate = s3.transactiondate order by s2.[tran_Number] desc)x 
order by s2.[tran_Number]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `ROW_NUMBER` and then retain the second record with record the inner ordering you are currently using.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ms.MemberId,
        ms.col1,
        s1.col2,
        s2.col3,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s2.[tran_Number] DESC) rn
    FROM MemberSample ms 
    INNER JOIN sample1 s1
        ON s1.MemberId = ms.MemberId
    INNER JOIN sample2 s2
       ON s2.MemberId = s1.MemberId
    INNER JOIN sample3 s3
        ON s3.MemberId = s2.MemberId
    WHERE
        ms.MemberId = '001' AND
        s1.creationdate = s3.transactiondate
) t
where t.rn = 2;
```

I am guessing as to the columns you want to select, but don't use `SELECT *`, rather just list out the columns you want.

Note that if ties could be an issue, then we might want to rethink this and use a rank function instead.

Comment: Hi in the t part have a squiggly line and still i run it to know the  error so the  message is this "The column 'MemberId' was specified multiple times for 't'."

Comment: @KeyBirdPadilla _Don't_ use `SELECT *` if you can avoid it.  Just list out the exact columns you want to select.  The error is being caused due to multiple columns from different tables called `MemberId`.

Comment: There is any way that I can select the last 2nd raw automatically because I want to select the all last 2nd row transaction.

Comment: If my initial answer did not work, then it doesn't work.  What is the issue with listing out the columns?  Anyway, you have name collisions and that isn't a desirable thing from a reporting point of view.

Comment: Hi  last question how can I select all last transaction of all of my members

Comment: Just use `WHERE t.rn = 1` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Still only one can select it not all

Comment: I don't understand what you want.